# Reusing GRPS Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, grpc

When i use samplerGRPC Request in Jmeter it gets response 200/300/400/500 and then connection closes and cannot be reused.
I want to reuse this connection for new request or making gRPC calls. Maybe it has the same option as "keepalive"?
Now my TestPlan looks like:

```
--Thread Group
  --GRPC Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about [this plugin](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request) I don't see any possibility to control how connections are being used/re-used, you might want to implement it yourself by invoking [ClientCaller](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request/blob/master/src/main/java/vn/zalopay/benchmark/core/ClientCaller.java) class methods from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)